# What does {"ResourceType":"runtimeconfig.v1beta1.waiter","ResourceErrorCode":"504","ResourceErrorMessage":"Timeout expired."} mean?

Tags: google-compute-engine

what does the message mean when deploying a Check Point CloudGuard IaaS High Availability (BYOL)?

{"ResourceType":"runtimeconfig.v1beta1.waiter","ResourceErrorCode":"504","ResourceErrorMessage":"Timeout expired."}

Comment: Please updatge your queston with more details - describe your setup etc. It's not possible to answer your question in the current state.

Answer (score 1):

Just forgot to enable "private access" on VPC level. The error message is not that "precise".

Comment: Did you found the solution ? If so please update your answer more details what you did exactly which will be more usefull for community

Comment: The solution is to enable "Google private access" during VPC creation. The error message is unfortunately not given any match to that specific topic.